# APPSEC-1034 help - still 404ing

Tags: magento-1.8, extensions, adminhtml, supee-6788

I have changed my config.xml so that it doesnt have admin however my when I try to access the extension in the back in its still sending me to a 404 page.

Below is my config.xml, could someone advise what else I need to do

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Namespace_ModuleName>
                <version>0.9</version>
            </Namespace_ModuleName>
        </modules>
        <global>
            <models>
                <custom_export>
                    <class>Namespace_ModuleName_Model</class>
                </custom_export>
            </models>
            <helpers>
                <custom_export>
                    <class>Namespace_ModuleName_Helper</class>
                </custom_export>
            </helpers>
        </global>
        <admin>
            <routers>
                <adminhtml>
                    <args>
                        <modules>
                            <Namespace_ModuleName after="Mage_Adminhtml">Namespace_ModuleName_Adminhtml</Namespace_ModuleName>
                        </modules>
                    </args>
                </adminhtml>
            </routers>
        </admin>
        <adminhtml>
            <events>
                <adminhtml_block_html_before>
                    <observers>
                        <option_in_custom_export>
                            <class>custom_export/Observer</class>
                            <method>includeOption</method>
                        </option_in_custom_export>
                    </observers>
                </adminhtml_block_html_before>
            </events>
        </adminhtml>
    </config>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is an old question and chances you might have already solved it. Even then I would like to post here in-case anyone runs in to this problem.

There is a tool [here](https://github.com/rhoerr/supee-6788-toolbox) which can analyse your magento installation and fix it.

If you have already solved the problem; please post how did you solve it.

Thanks,
Abhishek